# How to block scrolling for the user while Scroll-Snap is scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

Currently, the user can scroll back before the scroll has snapped to the next element. I want to prevent this and block scrolling inputs from the user until the transition is finished. Is this possible? Using `overflow: hidden` or `scrollTo()` is not an option because I want the window itself to keep scrolling.

Comment: Hello. Do you want to block the scrollbar interactivity during the scroll animation?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov yes, but also prevent scrollwheel and keyboard scrolling

Comment: Show your code, pls.